# Windows 7: How can I get a list of all Windows user names in .Net?

Tags: .net, windows-7

Is there a simple way to get the names of all the user names of a local Windows 7 machine using .Net? So if I had a machine named MyPC, and it had 3 users MyPC\Mike, MyPC\Bob, and MyPC\Steve, I'd just want to be able to query to get Mike, Bob, and Steve. Of course, I don't care if they have the computer name attached, or not, as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/enumerate_system_users.aspx

Comment: Thank you. That does what I want it to do, only the results aren't exactly what I'd expect. My PC has only one user account, Mike, which is an administrator, and I have guests turned off. Yet when I run this:  SelectQuery("Win32_UserAccount","Domain='Mike-PC'"), I get three results: Administrator, Mike, and Guest. I would expect to get only Mike. Are Administrator and Guest present by default?

Answer (score 2):

If no-one comes up with a better way, you could enumerate the \Users folder and use the folders in there as representations. (Providing each user has logged in and the network isn't using roaming profiles)