# Get all Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData in C# .NET

Tags: c#

I want to get the Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData of all users from windows service installed as a local system with admin privileges.

Example:

If I have Tom, Matt and Christine users, I need:

> C:\Users\Matt\AppData\Local
>
> C:\Users\Tom\AppData\Local
>
> C:\Users\Christine\AppData\Local

Thanks in advance!

Comment: First have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2299100/windows-7-how-can-i-get-a-list-of-all-windows-user-names-in-net)

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code by which you can find out the ApplicationData path for any user -

1. First find out the name of the current user.
2. Find out the Application Data path.
3. Now replace the current users name from application data path.

   ```
   /// <summary>
   /// GetAppDatafolder
   /// </summary>
   private static void GetAppDatafolder(string otherUserName)
   {
       var currentUserIdentity = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
       var currentUserName = (currentUserIdentity.Contains(@"\")) ? (currentUserIdentity.Split('\\')[1]) : currentUserIdentity;
       var currentAppDataPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
       var otherUserAppDataPath = currentAppDataPath.Replace(currentUserName, otherUserName);

       Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Current User AppDataPath : {0}", currentAppDataPath));
       Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} AppDataPath : {1}", otherUserName, otherUserAppDataPath));
   }
   ```